# What Part of the domain name is the most hierarchal in terms of DNS Name Space?

Tags: dns, communication

I'm reading through a book on DNS name spacing and it mentions hierarchy but it does so in such a way thats so confusing I'm having trouble of telling which was it means it the most hierarchal.

The Example is:

```
exp.cs.sentra.edu.au
```

Which starts the hierarchy, it is the exp or the au?
I'm thinking its the au:
    au
        edu
            sentra
                   cs
                      exp

Thanks for all the help! :D

Comment: *most hierarchal* makes no sense; for pretty much the same reason as *a little bit pregnant* makes no sense.

Comment: Off-topic? I hope it wasn't closed because of grammar, because as far as I can tell, the doman name applies to both DNS and communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "au" is the topmost in the hierarchy and its called TLD (Top-Level Domain). The next one - "edu" is a second-level domain name, etc. You can read more details in this page: [Domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name)

Comment: Thanks for that, I thought as much but Didin't really wanna continue on with just an assumption, thanks for the extra information!

Answer (score 1):

It should be correct to say exp is the most hierarchical. As hierarchy is start from that root element, following elements are added after the existence of exp in

> exp.cs.sentra.edu.au.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I thought that initially except which I was looking though the DNS queries, it said that it first visits au, then edu, etc. until it reaches the destination address if it cant find it initially at the local server, which was what mainly confused me.

Comment: DNS is like a tree, so parent wil be traversed first to reach upto the desired child.